# Nodemon keeps constantly restarting, while I search for files, or start new server

Tags: javascript, restart, nodemon

I was having issue with nodemon, as soon as I search for files ir VSC sidebar, or, sometimes, start server, nodemon starts to restart "due to changes" even-though there are no changes. This keeps going for several minutes, and then my PC crashes.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Forgive me being a little salty, but "enter image description here" should not be taken as a friendly suggestion.. I not only helps the visually impaired, but everyone else who might consider clicking the link. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, first time using SO :)

Comment: You would need to use the verbose mode to figure out which files are causing the restart. `nodemon -V  script.js`

Comment: It looks like it loops through all files that are in this project. It doesn't matter if I use different projects, or cmd, gitbash, or atom, VSC. Tried to uninstall and install different versions of nodemon, and node. Sometimes my antivirus scans and nodemon is triggered..

Answer (score 0):

Try running nodemon with delay option.

```
nodemon YOURFILE --delay 1
```

This fixed it for me.